# iOS:Issue with Silent Push triggering Local Notification

Tags: ios, localnotification, silentpush

In my app I am using a daily silent push to trigger some calculations inside my app and based on the calculation result I am triggering a local notification.

Say for example: A daily goal.

Once the silent notification reaches my app, I trigger a background method to calculate the user data and compare whether his/ her data achieved a goal and if yes I trigger a local notification so that user can open the app and check.

It is not working consistently, sometimes I get it and sometimes don't. When I debugged, what I saw was that the execution get paused in between and execution gets resumed only if the user opens the app again or I trigger a silent push again. Not sure why the background execution (the calculation) gets paused, and if I trigger a push or if i manually try to open the app, I can see the breakpoint appearing back and it continues from the place it was paused.

I am wondering whether it is because of some time limit??

**UPDATE:**

I am using UrbanAirshipSDK and they have some handlers overridden and I am using the below method to handle the notification. This is written in the appdelegate and gets called when I get a notification when app is in background.

```
/**
 * Called when a push notification is received while the app is running in the background
 * for applications with the "remote-notification" background mode.  
 * Overridden by receivedBackgroundNotification:fetchCompletionHandler.
 *
 * @param notification The notification dictionary.
 */
- (void)receivedBackgroundNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification;
```

I first check for content-available in the payload and treat as silent and do the calculations. This works fine intermittently but not consistently. I am closing towards release dates and I really worried.

Comment: what does this calculation involve?

Comment: Coredata fetch and comparison of values fetched with the threshold goal values. Size of records data is very small

Comment: show the code you're using, you should have ample time for a fetch and local comparison

Comment: Due to some NDA issues, I wont be able to paste the code, I will try to write a generic version add it here, but what I am trying to figure out is why it works sometimes and sometimes dont

Comment: Yes, show some code. You probably need to call `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` to get enough background time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

In this case you should not forget to call completion handler and according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) you have only 30 seconds to do so:

> As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the
>   block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your
>   app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the
>   notification and call the specified completion handler block. In
>   practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done
>   processing the notification. The system tracks the elapsed time, power
>   usage, and data costs for your app’s background downloads. Apps that
>   use significant amounts of power when processing remote notifications
>   may not always be woken up early to process future notifications.